# how to make a button that redirects to the previous page only if it is on my site

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to make a button that redirects the user to the previous page only if it is on my site, otherwise this button would redirect to the home page

I read in the doc that we could not read the history urls but only redirect, so I ask the question if anyone knows any tips to do this

```
function Back_on_site() {
    if (previous_domain == my_domain)
        history.back()
    else
        window.location.href = "my_site/home"
}
```

Comment: at the back-end side I'd like to consider HTTP request headers, see  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META  . 
HTTP_HOST contains the host name, you can compare it with your domain name.

Comment: have you try add a history or location prop to the request? if it's `unfined` then redirect to your homepage